# How to set different width of jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Iam using Elastislide Responsive Carousel Slider [LINK](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/)

I modification code, I want 1 page show  2 slider with different width

i want slider 1 width : 100%  and slider 2 width : 50%

this my code, i confused :(

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elastislide.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.17475.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

            <ul id="carousel">
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/5.jpg" alt="image05" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/6.jpg" alt="image06" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/7.jpg" alt="image07" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/8.jpg" alt="image08" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/9.jpg" alt="image09" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/10.jpg" alt="image10" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/11.jpg" alt="image11" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/12.jpg" alt="image12" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/13.jpg" alt="image13" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/14.jpg" alt="image14" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/15.jpg" alt="image15" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/16.jpg" alt="image16" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/17.jpg" alt="image17" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/18.jpg" alt="image18" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/19.jpg" alt="image19" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px"src="images/small/20.jpg" alt="image20" /></a></li>
            </ul>

            <br/><br/>
                <ul id="carousel2">
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/5.jpg" alt="image05" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/6.jpg" alt="image06" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/7.jpg" alt="image07" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/8.jpg" alt="image08" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/9.jpg" alt="image09" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/10.jpg" alt="image10" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/11.jpg" alt="image11" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/12.jpg" alt="image12" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/13.jpg" alt="image13" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/14.jpg" alt="image14" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/15.jpg" alt="image15" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/16.jpg" alt="image16" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/17.jpg" alt="image17" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/18.jpg" alt="image18" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px" src="images/small/19.jpg" alt="image19" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img width="150px" height="160px"src="images/small/20.jpg" alt="image20" /></a></li>
            </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $( '#carousel' ).elastislide();

        $( '#carousel2' ).elastislide();

    </script>
</body>
```

**elastislide.css**

```
.elastislide-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.elastislide-wrapper.elastislide-loading {
    background-image: url(../images/loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.elastislide-horizontal {
    padding: 10px 40px;
}


.elastislide-carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.elastislide-horizontal ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.elastislide-horizontal ul li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}


.elastislide-carousel ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li a img {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid white;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Navigation Arrows */

.elastislide-wrapper nav span {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat 4px 3px;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}


.elastislide-horizontal nav span {
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top: -11px;
}


.elastislide-horizontal nav span.elastislide-next {
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
    background-position: 4px -17px;
}
```

**jquery.elastislide.js** This code in link > [LINK](http://pastebin.com/9weX5SEe)

**modernizr.custom.17475.js** This code in link > [LINK](http://pastebin.com/NtSCxWsj)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the gallery containers don't have any settings in css.
Try adding this to your css:

```
#carousel,#carousel2
{
    position:relative;
}
#carousel
{
   width:100%; /*or whatever width you want*/
}

#carousel2
{
   width:50%; /*or whatever width you want*/
}
```

Comment: Don't work, slider 1 and slider 2 still 100% 
whereas slider 2 i set width 50%

Check this code > http://pastebin.com/3V9Ue3YT

Comment: Try this edit. And if you have a workspace on some internet hosting, it will be much easier if you give me the url or make a jsfiddle

Comment: I confused using jsfiddles cause not working

whereas i'm already includes external js and css

http://jsfiddle.net/m4sL3gf4/1/